# Shadow on bottom image like facebook

Tags: css

I would like know how is made the shadow on bottom image, i tried to check to the source code but I not found nothing. Any idea? Thank you

example in the cover image or see in the widget friend on the your profile page under the name there is a shadow for see better the name of color white

Comment: A shadow like what..? Facebook is huge, what exactly are you referring to?

Comment: You mean the background when a modal appears? Can you add a snapshot image to the question?

Comment: @fabrizio, can you take a screen shot, crop out the relevant parts, post it on imgur, and add the url to your post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be looking for a gradient. An option is to do this with an image, however this can be done with css as well. Check out [this page](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/). Or search Google/Bing/.. for *css3 gradient*.

I've made a quick [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pq69c/) of what I generated in the generator I linked that might fit your needs. You can change the background-color to whatever you want (in the example I set it to red) to show it is transparant.

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(43,43,43,0) 0%, rgba(43,43,43,0) 40%, rgba(43,43,43,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(43,43,43,0)), color-stop(40%,rgba(43,43,43,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(43,43,43,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(43,43,43,0) 0%,rgba(43,43,43,0) 40%,rgba(43,43,43,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(43,43,43,0) 0%,rgba(43,43,43,0) 40%,rgba(43,43,43,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(43,43,43,0) 0%,rgba(43,43,43,0) 40%,rgba(43,43,43,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(43,43,43,0) 0%,rgba(43,43,43,0) 40%,rgba(43,43,43,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#002b2b2b', endColorstr='#2b2b2b',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

## UPDATE

Looking at the Facebook code, it does seem that they are using an image to overlay the image. If you look at the source, you will see that `a#fbCoverImageContainer.coverWrap.coverImage` has **two important children**, the `img.coverPhotoImg.photo.img`, that contains the image of the background. Often this image will expand further than the height of the banner itself, since only part of the image is shown. The **other** important child is `div.coverBorder`. Looking at it's source it has following css:

```
background: url(/rsrc.php/v2/yJ/r/UgNUNkKQar6.png) bottom left repeat-x;
```

This is a 1x95px image creating the overlay. [image: The image fb uses]

I've fumbled around a little, getting to [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h4SWC/). This is the code I used:

**html**

```
<div class='myHeader'>
    <img src='http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-747-438-1.jpg' />
    <div class='coverBorder'></div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.myHeader{
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    height:315px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.coverBorder{
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/UGqidBk.png) bottom left repeat-x;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    top:0;
}
```

If you look at the fiddle, you can clearly see that the image expands outside of the div, but the `overflow:hidden;` hides this. Currently the overlay extends outside of the image because the `div.myHeader` has no width so it gets set to 100%. Give it 500px and you will see you can easily scale it.

Comment: @fabrizio: I've updated my answer with the way Facebook appears to be doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Using a gradient background. I'm assuming you're talking about the homepage before you login. If you really mean shadow please be more specific.

Edit in response to comment:

Yes. That is not a shadow, but a gradient background image repeated.

```
background: url(background-url.png) bottom left repeat-x;
```

Use google image search and search for term "gradient".

This is achieved by taking a small slice of the image and repeating it as a background along the x axis.

Comment: example in the cover image

Comment: I'm not on Facebook, and will not register just to see what you mean. Show a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Create a shadow class in your css file

```
.shadowThing
{
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px 2px #333;
}
```

Then apply it to a div (or something else) in your HTML.

```
<div class="shadowThing">
    <!--some content here-->
</div>
```

Comment: No, i mean the shadow under the name. thank you the same for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS [**`box-shadow`**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp) property

The syntax is:

> box-shadow: h-shadow v-shadow blur spread color inset;

so use like this:

```css
.shadow {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px #888888;
}
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/WRrx2) for an example

It will look like this when applied to a block element with height and width properties set.

[image: demo]